# Calling Calendar object from another class throws NullPointerException

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, null, calendar, initialization

I want to assign Calendar or Date object which is a global variable in another class. In class `Class1` I initialize date object like his:

```
Calendar date1;
date1 = Calendar.getInstance();
```

In `Class2` I do this:

```
Calendar date2 = Class1.date1;
```

Why does it work good if I assign `Class1.date1` to `date2` inside any method in `Class2` but doesn't work if I declare `date2` as global variable and assign value `Class1.date1`? (In this case there will be NullPointerException thrown.)

Comment: This is probably a problem with the initialization order of the two classes. Such could for instance happen if they both depend on each other. We would need a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to be able to tell for sure.

Answer (score 0):

You simply can't update a global variable without `static` with another anytype variable because global variables are also class instances and they have to be `static` to save all the changes that you done on them.

Comment: the variable date1 is public and static; variable date2 is static but I am still getting NullPointerException.

Comment: Then you should look [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it) place to fix it. Because this case has nothing to do about NullPointerException.